# Make POST request from Mule ESB

Tags: post, mule, httprequest

I'm stuck with making correct HTTP request to web server (running under PHP).
I need to send POST request with property `json` and some value, for example `{ "employee_id":191, "date":"2015-08-11", "time":"14:26:00" }`.

It's working if I make a request from Postman or cURL for example, the request will look something like this

```
POST /DeliveryDetails/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.100:80
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

json=%7B+%22employee_id%22%3A191%2C+%22date%22%3A%222015-08-11%22%2C+%22time%22%3A%2214%3A26%3A00%22+%7D
```

Also I can send with conntent type `multipart/form-data`

```
POST /DeliveryDetails/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.100:80
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{ "employee_id":191, "date":"2015-08-11", "time":"14:26:00" }
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

or with cURL

```
curl -d "json={ \"employee_id\":191, \"date\":\"2015-08-11\", \"time\":\"14:26:00\" }" http://192.168.0.100:80/DeliveryDetails/
```

But when I'm trying to make request from Mule ESB it's not working since the request is incorrect.

The flow looks like this

```
<sub-flow name="my-flow">
    <logger message="Request: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log request"/>
    <http:request config-ref="request-HTTP" path="/DeliveryDetails/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP call" />
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="Response: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log response"/>
</sub-flow>
```

`#[payload]` contains the value `{ "employee_id":191, "date":"2015-08-11", "time":"14:26:00" }` 
and if I do it like this the body would simply contain it (without additional information like `Content-Type`, I think thats the problem).

I have tried to add `query-param`

```
<http:request-builder >
    <http:query-param paramName="json" value="#[payload]" />
</http:request-builder>
```

or use `message-properties-transformer`

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="json" value="#[payload]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

but the result is still the same.

**EDIT**

The HTTP configuration look like this

```
<http:request-config name="request-HTTP" 
                     host="192.168.0.100" 
                     port="80"
                     doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />
```

Also tried to set `Content-Type` with

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="Property"/>
```

and

```
<http:request-builder>
    <http:query-param paramName="json" value="#[payload]"/>
    <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
</http:request-builder>
```

However the body I'm receiving is still just `payload`, without other properties for example `json=` or `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"`

Comment: Just to clarify, the ```query-param``` option in the request builder will generate a request like path?paramName=value, it will not send that in the body as a form.

Comment: I think the problem is because the post body has to be in application/x-www-form-encoded format. Try converting your JSON payload to HashMap first via json-to-object-transformer. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920203/mule-esb-how-to-create-a-http-request-with-post-method-sending-parameters-alo) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the payload is just the JSON data, that's what will be sent in most scenarios. Your curl example sets the "json=" part to the body. So there are a couple of options here:

1. Modify the payload to add the body you want as you do with curl and set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
2. Send multipart content by adding the data as an attachment. In your case try:

`<sub-flow name="my-flow">
    <logger message="Request: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log request"/>
    <set-attachment attachmentName="json" value="#[payload]" contentType="application/json"/>
    <http:request config-ref="request-HTTP" path="/DeliveryDetails" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP call" />
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="Response: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log response"/>
</sub-flow>`

3. Set the payload to be a map containing a key "json" with the payload as value. This should make Mule send a form request without you setting the Content-Type explicitly to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `path="/DeliveryDetails"`

You can follow the following config :-

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="192.168.0.100" port="80"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

and in the Mule flow or sub flow and set the **Content-Type** as follows:-

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/DeliveryDetails" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP call" />
<logger message="Input JSON message ****** #['\n'+ message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

You can configure the **Content-Type** here as per your requirement

You can also refer here :- [How do I force the HTTP Request Connector to use a certain Content-Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735277/how-do-i-force-the-http-request-connector-to-use-a-certain-content-type)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried it, but it did not helped. The path and HTTP configuration is correct, I'm receiving message on the other side, however server could not parse the request and returns error.

Comment: If you are receiving the response , then what exception are you getting ??? Pls put the full exception details here and also the response you are getting